# calling java script function via script tag

Tags: javascript, html

when i try to load script and call functions present in  my script it is showing as function is not defined.
below is my html file

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
  <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v4.1.1">
  <title>Magic Bricks</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{templateInfo.url}}/css/custom.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark customTopBar">
    <a class="navbar-brand navLogo" href="#">MAGIC BRICKS</a>

    <a class="nav-link loginLink ml-auto" href="#">
      <img class='navProfileImage' src="{{templateInfo.url}}/images/userProfile.png" alt='profile' />
      LOGIN
    </a>
  </nav>

  <main role="main" class="bgImage">
    <div class="text-center col-md-12">
      <h1 class="landingHeadingCss">
        Properties for <strong>Sale </strong>in <strong>Hyderabad</strong>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="landingSearchCard card">
      <div class="d-flex mb-3">
        <div class="activeSearchTab">Sale</div>
        <div class="searchTab ml-5">Rent</div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mb-3 customInput row mx-0">
        <div class="input-group-prepend searchButton col-3 px-0">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="city" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-auto" placeholder="Search for locality..."
          aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append searchButton col-auto px-0">
          <!-- <a class="input-group-text" href="{{templateInfo.url}}api/searchProperties?city=Hyderabad">Search</a> -->
          <button onclick="reload()" id="basic-addon2" class="input-group-text">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="application/json" src='../services/reload.service.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my reload.service.js

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

import config from '../config/config';

const serverUrl = config.localUrl;

function reload() {
  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>.")
  let url = serverUrl + "api/searchProperties";
  fetch(url, { method: 'GET', headers: { "Content-Type": "application/javascript" } }).then(response =>
    console.log(response))
}

export {
  reload
}
```

when i click on search button it is showing as reload is undefined.
How to resolve this

Any explaination is welcome and appreciated,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think your error is here:

script type="application/json" src='../services/reload.service.js'

Why do you put "application/json" since you are importing a .js file ?

Make sure you have added ' script type = "application/javascript" , or nothing , because that should be the default value.
I think the problem is with you export. I don't know which framework you are using . If it's pure javascript , you can remove this :
export {
reload
}
As you are already importing the javascript file , all the functions are automatically imported.  Please look at the screenshot this picture :
[image]

Comment: when i remove tye="application/json" i am getting an error as Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:5112/services/reload.service.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. @Tony Keith

Comment: I've updated my answer , because I can not put screenshots here

Comment: When you *have* `type="application/json"` the browser doesn't even try to load the JavaScript because you told it that it isn't JS. When you remove it, you expose a different problem: The server is sending back something it claims is HTML. So either the URL is wrong, the server is sending the wrong MIME type for JS, or a URL that the server will send the JS for doesn't exist.

Comment: @Tony Keith i am using node.js and express framework even after removing export{reload} there is no progress

Comment: Your use of ES6 module code (and node module resolution rules, and modules designed for use in Node and not a browser) in a client-side JS file will cause problems, but you won't experience them until you can persuade the server to actually send the JS file to the browser.